# Failed to connect PostgreSQL in Kubernetes

Tags: postgresql, go, kubernetes, linkerd

I am using Kubernetes. I have two pods.

In one pod, it is running a server. Here is the part of codes trying to connect PostgreSQL service in another pod.

```
import (
    "context"
    "github.com/jackc/pgx/v4/pgxpool"
    "github.com/rs/zerolog/log"
)

databaseURL := "postgres://admin:passw0rd@my-database-service.hm:40072/my_db"
pg, err := pgxpool.Connect(context.Background(), databaseURL)
if err != nil {
    log.Error().Err(err).Msg("conn.Close")
    return nil
}
```

Currently, above code gives the error

> {"level":"error","error":"failed to connect to `host=my-database-service.hm user=admin database=my_db`: dial error (dial tcp 10.43.140.140:40072: connect: connection refused)","time":1627849943,"message":"conn.Close"}

However, after I ssh into the server pod, I can successfully connect the PostgreSQL pod by `psql`.

```
/usr/src/app # psql --host=my-database-service.hm --port=40072 --dbname=my_db --username=admin --password
Password: 
psql (13.3)
Type "help" for help.

my_db=#
```

I tried to restart my server pod to make sure it runs after PostgreSQL database is ready, and still got same error.

Any suggestion for further debugging would be helpful. Thanks!

---

**UPDATE**

I am actually using Linkerd. Might be related with

https://linkerd.io/2.10/features/protocol-detection/

I tried to change the PostgreSQL to default port 5432, but still have issue. Will update if find the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some experiments, I can confirm my issue is not related with Linkerd.

I think my PostgreSQL containerPort/targetPort is still using the default 5432. And it exposed by ClusterIP inside of the network by port 40072, which is why I don't need [mark the port as opaque](https://linkerd.io/2.10/features/protocol-detection/#marking-a-port-as-opaque) in Linkerd.

It turns out that after adding `os.Exit(1)`,

```
pg, err := pgxpool.Connect(context.Background(), databaseURL)
if err != nil {
    log.Error().Err(err).Msg("conn.Close")
    os.Exit(1) // <- this helps
}
```

my Kubernetes will help restart the server pod when it fails initially to wait the PostgreSQL is ready.

After a few times restarts, the server pod can connect PostgreSQL well now.

I think if I manually restarts more times early, it might help too. But definitely not reliable like this way letting Kubernetes to help restart.